# How can i pass a function through defaultChecked in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create an edit procedure to edit an event and I have a checkbox element where you can choose the member you want to invite through your event. I defined a function to check the members that are already invited to the event but when I render the page the only member checked is the creator of the event. I debug the function and it returns the correct values so I don't understand why the others are not automatically checked. Can you suggest me something or do you see some errors?

React code

```
{modifyEvent && (
      <div className="InputEntry">
        <div className="InputLabel">Modify members</div>
        <div className="container" style={{ overflow: "auto" }}>
          {team_members.map((member) => (
            <Form.Check
              key={member.id}
              type="checkbox"
              label={
                typeof member === "object"
                  ? member.member
                  : member
              }
              id={`member-${member.id}`}
              disabled={member.member === task.member}
              defaultChecked={
                isMemberIncluded(
                  member.member,
                  eventMembers,
                  task.member
                ).toString() === "true"
              }
              onChange={(event) =>
                setEventMembers((prevMembers) => {
                  if (event.target.checked) {
                    return [...prevMembers, member];
                  } else {
                    return prevMembers.filter(
                      (prevMember) => prevMember !== member
                    );
                  }
                })
              }
            />
          ))}
```

Function code

```
export function isMemberIncluded(member, eventMembers, task_m) {
  if (task_m === member) {
    return true;
  } else {
    for (const m of eventMembers) {
      if (member === m.member) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```